# Failing on call to _mm_loadu_si128() with AESNI intrinsics enabled

Tags: gcc, centos, intel, crypto++

We are compiling a 32bit application that links with a static build of `cryptopp`.

> **gcc :** 4.4.7
>   **CPU :** Intel Xeon E5-2680
>   **OS :** CentoOS 6.5
>   **Crypto++ :** 5.6.2

Our program compiles and runs fine on this machine. When we attempt to run on

> **CPU :** Intel Xeon X5690
>   **OS :** CentoOS 6.5
>   **gcc :** 4.4.6

We are getting a segmentation fault in cryptopp -> rijndael.cpp -> Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey() call to _mm_loadu_si128()

If we build cryptopp with CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE set to 0 everything runs ok.  It seems like AES-NI should be available on this server, and the cryptopp call to HasAESNI() returns true.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this, or how to track down further?

Comment: `_mm_loadu_si128` is `MOVDQU`. I believe its a SSE2 instruction. Did you compile Crypto++ and your program on the Intel Xeon X5690 machine (or did you copy it over from another machine)? Is the microcode up to date on the Intel Xeon X5690 (I believe that instruction is emulated with microcode)?

Comment: If we compile on the X5690, it runs on that machine ok.  We get the error when compiling on the E5-2680, and copying to the X5690.  I will look into the microcode, not too familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We get the error when compiling on the E5-2680, and copying to the X5690.

Oh, that's interesting. Try adding `-mtune=pentium4` to `CXXFLAGS`. The Intel Xeon E5-2680 has the AVX instruction set; while the Intel Xeon X5690 only has SSE 4.2. Crypto++ uses the the double quadword multiply (`PCLMULQDQ`) and `AES-NI` instructions from the AVX instruction set (which the other processor lacks).

If `-mtune=pentium4` does not work, then you are going to have to disable via `CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE`. Now that I think about it, that's what you are probably going to have to do since this is a compile time feature selection, and not a runtime feature selection.

Comment: had to just stick with CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE.  Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU **E5606**  @ 2.13GH" don't support "**AESNI**" instruction too.  I have compiled Crypto++ on "Intel Xeon **E312xx** (Sandy Bridge)",  and get the same error on "**E5606**"! Disable "AESNI" in the CMakeLists.txt file, turn on "DISABLE_AESNI" option. 
`option(DISABLE_AESNI "Disable AES-NI" ON)`